# How do I pass multiple variables to the bw_ProgressChanged function

Tags: vb.net, function, variables

I have a small VB.Net program that shows a progress form. On that box, I show a progress bar and a percentage complete in a text box. Both of these can be derived by a single integer, but now I've been asked to put a 'Details' text box on the progress form, which updates with text to show how the job is doing.

My question - how do I pass both the percentage, and the text details to the `ProgressChanged()` function? I've tried passing an array and an object, but I can't seem to get it right. Thanks.

I'm calling the function like this (from the `bw_DoWork()` function) -

```
details = "Textbox details will go here"
progress = (100 / (UBound(servers) + 1)) * (i + 1)
bw.ReportProgress(progress) ' How do I also pass 'details'?
```

And here is the function it self -

```
Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)

    Me.proProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Me.txtProgress.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "% complete..."
    'Me.txtDetails.Text = Me.txtDetails.Text & IIf(Me.txtDetails.Text <> "", vbCrLf, "") & e.details ' How do I also pass 'details'?

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create your own custom "status" object that contains all of the data you want to pass to whatever is handling the progress change. Then you include that in your call as part of the userState object.

```
Public Class MyObjectState
    Public Message As String
    Public StatusState As String  
    Public Whatever as Integer
    Public Whosit as Decimal
End Class

...

Dim currentState as New MyObjectState()
currentState.Message = "blah blah blah"

bw.ReportProgress(progress, someMyObjectStateInstance)

...


Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e as ProgressChangedEventArgs) 
    Me.proProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage 

    Dim state as MyObjectState = CType(e.UserState, MyObjectState)
    'You can now use the state object with any of the instance information you need
    'At this point message would be "blah blah blah"

End Sub
```

This basically works like a "snapshot", so I would make your state object as detailed as possible, but only transfer what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm getting an error. In the `bw_ProgressChanged()` function, it's telling me `Make sure the source type is convertible to the destination type.` and pointing to the `Dim state...` line. Any ideas at all?

Comment: Never mind, I got it - I included your `bw_ReportProgress()` line, but that was of course already in my code, and including it twice (once in the wrong place!) was the cause of my issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DavidGard: Woops, sorry I didn't respond, I only now just got your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

The [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) event has an overload that accepts two parameters.
The first one is the Percentage that you get in the ProgressPercentage property.
The second one is an object that you get from the ObjectState property

So you can create a miniclass like this

```
Public Class bwObjectState
    Public String Details
End Class
```

Then when you call ReportProgress

```
Dim data As new bwObjectState()
data.Details = "Textbox details will go here"
progress = (100 / (UBound(servers) + 1)) * (i + 1)
bw.ReportProgress(progress, data)
```

The class object is useful if you plan to pass other values, but if you need to pass just a string you could simply assign the string to the second parameter

```
bw.ReportProgress(progress, "Textbox details will go here")
```

Of course, in the ProgressChanged event, you need to cast the ObjectState object back to its original type

```
Dim data  as bwObjectState = CType(e.UserState, bwObjectState)
```

or simply

```
Dim details  as String = CType(e.UserState, String)
```